# How objects are used through Spring?

Tags: spring

I have the following code:

```
package com.java2novice.test;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.java2novice.beans.SpringFirstTest;

public class SpringDemo {             
    public static void main(String a[]){
        String confFile = "applicationContext.xml";
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(confFile);
        SpringFirstTest sft = (SpringFirstTest) context.getBean("springTest");
        sft.testMe();
    }
}
```

`SpringFirstTest` is a simple class having `testMe()` as its method and then, I have an applicationContext.xml file. The xml file contains the bean below:

```
<bean id="springTest" class="com.java2novice.beans.SpringFirstTest" />
```

I am good with class file and XML file but the code written in the class "SpringDemo" is where I would need some input.

Comment: this is the code in xml file  <bean id="springTest" class="com.java2novice.beans.SpringFirstTest" />
</beans>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `applicationContext.xml` is the xml file which contains all your beans(or object) that you define.

**Note: it is basically the IoC (Inversion of Control) container which responsible for managing the lifecycle of the bean/beans.**

---

For instance, you have an `applicationContext.xml` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!-- Create a springTest bean or object -->
    <bean id = "springTest" class="com.java2novice.beans.SpringFirstTest"/>

</beans>
```

Here, in `<bean>` tag, `id` - name of the object and `class` -> fully qualified name.

---

Note : `<bean id = "springTest" class="com.java2novice.beans.SpringFirstTest"/>` is same as `SpringFirstTest springTest = new SpringFirstTest();`

---

Now, you have `SpringFirstTest` class like this below. For example:

```
    package com.java2novice.beans;

    public class SpringFirstTest {
        
       public SpringFirstTest() {
    
       }
    
       public void testMe() {
         System.out.println("Called the testMe method");
       }
    
    }
```

Now, the code you have provided :

```
package com.java2novice.test;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.java2novice.beans.SpringFirstTest;

public class SpringDemo {

    public static void main(String a[]){
        String confFile = "applicationContext.xml";
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(confFile);
        SpringFirstTest sft = (SpringFirstTest) context.getBean("springTest");
        sft.testMe();
    }
}
```

`ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` - This class picks up the applicationContext.xml file from classpath of the project.

`context.getBean("springTest")` - This piece of code picks the bean with name or id (springTest) mentioned in the applicationContext.xml.

Comment: @Request_1 Have you understood ??

Comment: Hi Anish ...I will write what i have understood ...I will start line by line..So ApplicationContext is a spring container that has all the beans & in this case bean = springtest   ......so this line String confFile = "applicationContext.xml does it mean that confFile = springtest

Comment: @Request_1 No, it is just the name of the file. Second line is the main thing. `ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(confFile);` -> this automatically picks up the applicationContext.xml file present in the project and then checks what are beans are present and stores them in context reference. After then, you get that bean from context reference by `context.getBean("springTest").`

Comment: and where can I see this option

Comment: @Request_1 Just beside my answer. You can see the votes. Below that tick is there. Just click on that it will become accepted answer.

Comment: @Request_1 Have you got the tick option ?